Angular- Primeng calender not displaying past end date values if minDate is current Date
Primeng calender not displaying past end date values if minDate is current Date, How to display the past dates  without using any [disabledDates] property?
Below is the code:
<p-calendar  [showIcon]="true"
inputId="icon" [minDate]="minDate" [showOtherMonths]="false" dateFormat="dd-M-yy"
formControlName="LICENCE_END_DATE"></p-calendar\>

When minDate is new Date(), then the value of formcontrolname - LICENCE_END_DATE is 'Wed Jul 31 2024 23:59:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' viz past value.
Even though both minDate and selected date formats are similar, p-calender control not displaying past value.

You have to set the minDate to null only then the values will be visible.
If you provide valid date, it must disabled the dates before the minDate.

I had the same issue and the following code fixed the problem:
minDate = new Date(
 Date.parse(
  ${new Date().getMonth() + 1}/${new Date().getDate()}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`
 )
);

This code snippet builds a date without the time. Normaly you get the exact datetime if you just build a new Date-Class without any arguments. But I think the CalenderModule has problems to show the minDate with a different time so I decided to set the time to 0.
For example:
It is 09th October 2024 and it's 7:25AM.
let date1 = new Date(),
console.log(date1) // Wed Oct 09 2024 07:26:14 GMT+0200

let minDate = new Date(
 Date.parse(
  ${new Date().getMonth() + 1}/${new Date().getDate()}/${new Date().getFullYear()}`
 )
);
console.log(minDate) // Wed Oct 09 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200


Would be nice if you could add an explanation.

@Bouke I added an explanation.

Try separating your parameters by commas.
Example
let minDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), new Date().getHours(), new Date().getMinutes());

